Uso de "segue" e "segue-se" no contexto de consequência lógica
No contexto da matemática, é muito comum fazer uso de sentenças com a seguinte estrutura:

Como x+1=3, segue-se que x=2.
Como x+1=3, segue que x=2.

Essas duas formas são aceitáveis do ponto de vista da norma culta da língua?

Não vejo motivos para o '-se'. O sentido indicado não é passivo nem reflexivo, x=2 segue e pronto.

@Quaestoria Creio que estaria errado dizer "conclui que x=2" ou "resulta-se que x=2". Nesse caso, qual diferença/semelhança entre "seguir", "resultar" e "concluir"? Há uma regra geral aplicável a esses casos que permite obter a regra correta para cada uma dessas situações?

Porque o verbo concluir é transitivo e neste caso permite-se o '-se' apassivador. Resultar é transitivo também neste contexto. Seguir no sentido de proceder é intransitivo.

Conclui algo quem conclui. X=2 não conclui nada porque não é pessoa. Sem menção de um sujeito, vale o '-se' apassivador. Mas o que segue segue, neste contexto não segue nada.

@Quaestoria Sigo teu argumento, contudo não é "seguir" um verbo pronominal aqui? Veja, e.g., aqui e aqui.

@stafusa Verdade. Nessa acepção, o '-se' é necessário.

Acho que com isso poder-se-ia formular uma resposta já.
